# Programmatically adding constraints in Swift does not work

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I added the following code to center a programmatically added view:

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
```

It doesn't work. The view is not centered. It is on the left still.

EDIT:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newView = LineChartView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    newView?.delegate = self
    newView?.drawBordersEnabled = true
    newView?.noDataText = "No Data"
    newView?.noDataTextDescription = "No Data"
    newView?.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    self.view.addSubview(newView!)
```

Comment: Can you show your code where `newView` is initialised please ?

Comment: Try to add `newView?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`

Comment: @hannad "Value of type 'LineChartView' has no member 'setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints'"

Comment: `newView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Also where abouts are you setting up your constraints for `newView`?

Comment: @ChristopherKevinHowell That line caused the view to disappear. I'm setting up the constraints by the original two lines of code I showed in my question.

Comment: You need to set more than just the center X - you need to constrain the Y as well, and potentially the width/height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick a side my friend, If you are using auto layout, don't initialise your objects with a `frame`. Try something like this...

```
var newView:LineChartView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newView = LineChartView()
    newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newView.delegate = self
    newView.drawBordersEnabled = true
    newView.noDataText = "No Data"
    newView.noDataTextDescription = "No Data"
    newView.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(newView)

    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
    newView.addConstraint(width)
    newView.addConstraint(height)
    let x = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(x)
    self.view.addConstraint(y)

}
```

If your `LineChartView` object is a subclass of `UIView` then this should work, and you should have a 50x50 object in the middle of your superview.

If you are going to be doing constraints like this in code you should consider using Apples [Visual Formatting Language](http://lukewakeford.co.uk/basic-vfl-constraints/).

Comment: Personally I would still initialise LineChartView with a frame of CGRectZero, given `initWithFrame:` is one of the two designated initializers of `UIView`. Yes, `init()` for `UIView` calls `initWithFrame:CGRectZero` anyways, but correct initialization flow is more explicit.

Comment: When I remove the frame and just have double brackets, the view disappears.

Comment: Actually I replaced my code with yours exactly and now it works. Answer accepted. Thanks.